# Shell script translate single into multiple lines based on a parameter

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I try to write a shell scrip for the following data

Input file **page.txt** with content:

```
enter a first page title<br><div style="margin-left: 40px;">enter a first point <br></div><div style="margin-left: 80px;">enter a second point<br></div><div style="margin-left: 120px;">enter a third point<br></div><div style="margin-left: 80px;"><br></div><div style="margin-left: 40px;"><br></div><div style="margin-left: 40px;"><br></div>
```

Algorithm :

```
Read the pages file
Replace <br> with newline
Replace <div style="margin-left: 40px;"> with 1 tab 
Replace <div style="margin-left: 80px;"> with 2 tab
Replace <div style="margin-left: 120px;"> with 3 tab
Replace <div style="margin-left: 160px;"> with 4 tab
```

i am trying to use this

```
tr '<br>' '\n' < page.txt
```

Expected output file

```
enter a first page title
    enter a first point 
        enter a second point
            enter a third point
```

Please tell tell how to write the script mentioned above..

Comment: `tr` just replaces characters, it cannot do what you are trying. use sed like `sed 's/<br>/\n/g'`for that.

Comment: it has to be a shell script? Cannot we use python or perl?

Comment: Shell scripts are generally quite unsuitable to this kind of problem, what exactly are your limitations? Bash only or anything that can run on the command line? Do you have any guarantees there won't be any nested divs? Will the file always adhere exactly to the format above (e.g. always a space between "margin-left" and the number of pixels, always the same number of pixels, etc.)? String parsing HTML is notoriously error-prone if you're not in total control of the format or using an actual DOM.

Comment: I need to do it using shell script only, format will be same, pixels will change in terms of 40, like 40, 80,120 etc..

Answer (score 1):

I don't like to handle XML tags without a parser, but in this specific case your data seems weird for it (bad formed) so [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) and the option to evaluate the replacement string in a substitution command is a good tool for the solution.

I use three substitution commands, the first one to replace all `<br>` with newlines, the second one to remove all close `div` tags, and the third one to look for the open `div` tags, extract the number of the attribute and use it to calculate how many tabs to insert:

```
perl -pe '
    s/<br>/\n/g; 
    s{</div>}{}g; 
    s{\Q<div style="margin-left: \E(\d+)\s*\Qpx;">}{"\t" x ($1/40)}ge
' infile
```

It yields:

```
enter a first page title
    enter a first point 
        enter a second point
            enter a third point
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is to replace the end of the line (not the `\n`, but the *end of the line*) with `<br>`, like so:

```
(echo line one; echo line two) | sed -e 's/$/<br>/'
```

or in your case:

```
sed -e 's/$/<br>/' < inputfile
```

Replacing the tabs at the beginning of the line is done similarly using the caret as the beginning-of-the-line marker. As a complete script:

```
TAB="$(echo -e "\t")"
sed -e "s/^$TAB$TAB$TAB$TAB\(.*\)/<div style=\"margin-left: 160px;\">\1<\/div>/ \
    -e "s/^$TAB$TAB$TAB\(.*\)/<div style=\"margin-left: 120px;\">\1<\/div>/ \
    -e "s/^$TAB$TAB\(.*\)/<div style=\"margin-left: 80px;\">\1<\/div>/ \
    -e "s/^$TAB\(.*\)/<div style=\"margin-left: 40px;\">\1<\/div>/ \
    -e 's/$/<br>/' \
   < inputfile > outputfile
```

Note 1: The `\` at the end means line continuation, so the above are 2 statements.

Note 2: I've assumed that you want a `</div>` at the end of the line as well, and just to show the escaping of the `/` in `</div>`.

Please note that for anything more complex you should consider using a Proper Extraction and Regex Language, like Perl. You probably will want to do something like group multiple lines that are indented the same way in one `<div>` for one.